# How to animate this kind of cloud?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, procedural

so i tried a new tutorial about making a landscape, and i want to animate this procedural generated cloud. the cloud itself is a shader, as far as i know in order to animate this kind i need to manipulate the the texture that make the cloud itself but because this is a shader i dont know how to do it. right now i'm using blender 2.93 rendering in cycles,

[image: render preview of the cloud and the shader tab]

thank you

Comment: It really depends on how the node group is created. If you press TAB while the group is selected or click on the icon in the top right of the node, you'll get to see the insides of the group. You'll most likely see a Texture Coordinate node. Plug a Mapping node after it and you'll be able to transform the input coordinates. Otherwise if there is some kind of noise node, set the type to 4D and tweak the W input to smoothly change the seed

Comment: oh yeah, i tried to open the tab and all the nodes come out. now pretty much i can work from it. thank you so much

Comment: you can also permanently open the node group by going CTRL ALT G while the group is selected or Node > Ungroup